# Adding Bootstrap UI Module to angularjs project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to add the bootstrap-ui module to my angular.js project. The documentation states that I simply have to add

```
angular.module('myModule', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

to get this working. But I can't find out how I would add this in any way. I've read the whole chapter of https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module and read lots of threads about it, but everything I tested didn't work so far.

my **app.js**:

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngCookies', 'ngResource', 'ngMessages', 'ngRoute', 'mgcrea.ngStrap'])
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
// followed by my routing
```

**myCtrl**

```
angular.module('MyApp')
    .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$rootScope', '$routeParams', '$resource', '$alert', 'MyService',
        function ($scope, $location, $rootScope, $routeParams, $resource, $alert, MyService) {
```

what I tried:

- adding *'ui.bootstrap'* after *'mgcrea.ngStrap'* in *app.js*
- adding *'ui.bootstrap'* after *'MyService' in *myCtrl*
- many more similar variations

The error messages I get depend on what I did. Since I'm probably completely on the wrong path at the moment I was hoping someone could tell me how I can add a module in angular.js correctly?

**edit** some error messages I encountered:

When I start my Crtl code with:

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ui.bootstrap'])
```

I get

```
[ng:areq] Argument 'NavbarCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
```

(navbarctrl is a completely different ctrl)

when I start my *app.js* with

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngCookies', 'ngResource', 'ngMessages', 'ngRoute', 'mgcrea.ngStrap', 'ui.bootstrap'])
```

I get

```
TypeError: object is not a function
```

In my `AuthService` I try to use $alert (this works without bootstrap-ui) like

```
$alert({
    title: 'Success!', //...
```

**edit 2: ** the problem seems to be that I can only use ngStrp OR ui.bootstrap (both use bootstrap underneath)

Comment: Can you copy errors from console here?

Comment: I added some error messages, but I'm afraid I don't think that they have anything to do with my problem. Since I don't know how to add the module the errors I posted are probably just followup errors

Comment: Sorry for stupid question, but you connect ui-bootstrap js file in html?

Comment: yeah I did that: <script src="vendor/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.min.js"></script>
(and bootstrap.css as well)

it's working to some extend (I get the errors and can't for example submit a form), but I see that my tabs which I implemented are correctly displayed

Comment: And in myctrl - ['$scope', '$location', '$rootScope', '$routeParams', '$resource', '$alert', 'MyService' - you don't close an array, maybe problem here?

Comment: the array is closed at the end of my Ctrl. I dont think I have a typo, since all my attempts didn't work I think I must be on a completely wrong path. Do I have to add the module in the app.js or in the ctrl?

Comment: Hm .. maybe you have conflict with ngStrap and ui.bootstrap?

Comment: it seems to me that is the case. probably I must decide which project I want to use. thanks for the tipp!

Answer (score 1):

Are you ensuring that Angular UI specific JS Files are sent from server to client through bundling or direct reference?

You have to inject dependency of module in your app: something like this angular.module('MyApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

Comment: I dont really know what I mean by that. At the moment I'm not sure how I can add bootstrap-ui (or any other module for that matter) to my project

Comment: You have to inject dependency of module in your app: something like this angular.module('MyApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

Comment: that's exactly what I did - I tried it in my app.js and in my ctrl

Comment: In your app.js you have not mentioned this dependency  'ui.bootstrap'  ..other dependencies are mentioned there

Comment: One of my many attempts was adding it at the end, but then I get the last error (from my post

Comment: @Markus you definitely need to have 'ui.bootstrap' in the list of your app's dependencies. So that last error you refer to seems to be the key. What file/line number is that last error from?